# get all parent id <ul> to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, parent

My html code :

```
<form>
<ol>
  <li id="1" name="grandparent">Grand Parent
    <ol>
      <li id="2" name="parent">Parent
         <ol>
           <li id="3" name="child">Child
         </ol>
      </li>
      <li id="4" name="parent2">Parent2
         <ol>
           <li id="5" name="child2">Child2
         </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="6" name="grandparent2">Grand Parent 2
  </li>
</ol>
</form>
```

On submit form, I want to get all parent like this :

[1] => 'grandparent', Parent

[2`//li id`] => 'parent', Parent => [1`//id of parent`]

[3] => 'child', Parent => [2]

[4] => 'parent2', Parent => [1]

[5] => 'child2', Parent => [4]

[6] => 'grandparent2', Parent

> Please help me to get all parent id on javascript.

Comment: Sorry your question not very clear to me. Are is this <ol> list dynamicly or always the same?.

Comment: the <ol> just like that for example, just 3 level of parent. Can you help me for get array from that <ol>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect somethig like this. I use recursive function hence you can extend this very easily,

```js
function getJson()
{
 var finalJson = getChildLis(new Array(),$("#myform").children("ol"),"");
 alert(JSON.stringify(finalJson));
}


function getChildLis(jsonArray,currentEle,parent)
{
 $.each($(currentEle).children("li"),function(key,val){
  var curName = $(val).attr("name");
  var curId = $(val).attr("id");
  var jsonO = {};  
  jsonO[curId] = curName;
  jsonO.parent = parent;  
  jsonArray.push(jsonO);
  getChildLis(jsonArray,$(val).find("ol"),curId);
 });
 return jsonArray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myform" >
<ol>
  <li id="1" name="grandparent">Grand Parent
    <ol>
      <li id="2" name="parent">Parent
         <ol>
           <li id="3" name="child">Child
         </ol>
      </li>
      <li id="4" name="parent2">Parent2
         <ol>
           <li id="5" name="child2">Child2
         </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li id="6" name="grandparent2">Grand Parent 2
  </li>
</ol>
<input type="button" value="show Array" onclick="getJson()" >
</form>
```

Comment: thankyou very much, you saved my day! @Nishan Senevirathna